# Twitter API Friendship Create always returns 403 only for SOME specific users

Tags: php, error-handling, twitter, twitter-oauth

For certain users of my Twitter app, I am unable to create a friendship using the Rest API as I get a response code 403 FORBIDDEN for those users. It is the same users every time that for some reason I am unable to make friendship create requests on their behalf.

I have found that if a user deauthorizes my app, I get a 401 response when I try to create a new friendship for that user. So that is not the problem.

Has anyone else seen this? I do not have a problem with OAuth or anything like that as I have no issues making friendship creates for MOST of my app users but some of them always return 403. Any thoughts?

Also, I know the users are not hitting their daily follow limit. One particular user who always has this problem has tens of thousands of followers and only follows about 1,500. So I do not believe that is the issue either but I cannot find anything on the Internet about any other possibilities...

Also... note that it is NOT a 403 because the user already follows. I verified this by trying to get the user to follow a Twitter account that I know it does not currently follow.

Comment: According to the [API doco](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/friendships/create), it should "Returns a string describing the failure condition when unsuccessful" - have you checked for that?

Comment: perhaps it is that your app has read only permissions? and need to add a mobilephone number to your profile to enable writing permissions?